# Datatables plugin works with table of Four rows, but messes up when Fifth row is added

Tags: html, css, datatable, datatables

I am trying to use the DataTables plugin (datatables.net) in my web page. But is not working well with my dataset. So I obfuscated my data and wrote the given SSCCE to demonstrate the problem.

It is a `<table>` with four `<tr>`s in **[this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesss/bj44on6n/2/)**, and it works fine in this example.

But as soon as I add the fifth row `<tr>`, everything gets messed up, as shown in **[*this* JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesss/5zttLv5q/3/)**; that is there is *no longer* any Search bar or any traces of Pagination controls.

So the question is that how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you missed an `<td>` in your fith `<tr>`. If i copy one `<tr>` from your working fiddle i get a working table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a couple of things wrong - see this working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/41o91j0a/1/)

1. you were missing the jQuery library - so in the console I was seeing: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`
2. you were missing a column on that final row - the console gave the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined`